# Error in writing two arrays into a CSV file, one header in string and other numpy.float array

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, numpy

I get an array from my optimization algorithm named `Myresult` which is in numpy format, and I need to write it into a CSV file with headers, (first row includes headers, an array that I had defined in my code, and second row, the result vector) named `MyCSV.csv`, like:

```
Myheader = ['d1','d2','d3',....]
Myresult = [5.2,6.08,-0.09,....]

d1    d2     d3    ...
5.2   6.08   -0.09  ...
```

I wrote the code like:

```
import numpy
import csv
numpy.savetxt('MyCSV.csv', Myresult, delimiter=',')
with open('MyCSV.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(Myheader)
```

With the first line, I can easily write my numpy array in one column, but when I run the rest of code, it clears the column.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed the lines generating Myheader and Myresult.

Comment: ^this. Off the bat it can be said though, that you're passing a string where it expects a byte-like, and a numpy.float instead of an iterable(ie list, tuple, np.array). Just to state the (hopefully) obvious.

Comment: Thanks j4ck, I solved the first error, since in Python3, we should use 'w' instead of 'wb'

Comment: Thanks zezollo, but I'm afraid, i can't show how to create Myresult, since it's a result of optimization algorithm using Scipy, and it's gonna be very complicated to show here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writer.writerows()` needs list of lists (or iterable to be more general), i.e. one list per line to be written into the file. Your array is only 1D. So either use 
`writer.writerow(Myresult)` (note the singular `...row`) for one line in your file or reshape your array into a 2D array before writing.

**EDIT**

You can achieve all this with one line, using `numpy.savetxt()`:

```
numpy.savetxt('savetxt.csv', Myresult, header=' '.join(Myheader) + '\n', newline='',
              comments='')
```

Comment: but what about my header? sorry, I had to edit my question, since I realized that Myresult is a numpy array, and I can use "savetxt" command. So, my question changed. I really apologise

Comment: Use `writer.writerow(Myheader)`.

Comment: Great, thanks Mike, just do you know how can I remove # sign from the start of the line?

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in text mode.

`with open('MyCSV.csv', 'rt') as f:`